# Does Mailchimp remember deleted subscribers

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am currently testing using the API v3.0 to integrate MailChimp with an existing form on my website.

As I'm working I need to test the code at regular intervals. My problem is that when I delete my test subscriber through the Mailchimp interface and try to reuse that email again through my form, my form errors with:

```
 "title":"Member Exists","status":400 error code.
```

Does Mailchimp store or cache subscriber email addresses? I've looked around and can't find old records. It's been over 48 hours since using the test emails.

Comment: I've discovered from Mailchimp that the email address was still pending. Following that, when a subscriber is pending confirmation, POST calls fail. 

To get the email active again (I no longer have the confirmation email), I used a PUT call to change the pending status to subscribed and then I can fully delete the subscriber through the interface and reuse the subscriber email again in testing.

Comment: You can also just DELETE them through the API, if you want.

Comment: Thanks @TooMuchPete. How would you go about deleting through the API - would that be using CURL command?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, quite a simple fix.

The issue for me was that I was testing with `foo@bar.com` for example with Double-opt in (this means a client will get a confirmation email before being officially added to the subscriber list).

When a client completed the form to the registered their `status` is set to `pending` until the client then confirms their subscription to the by following the link in the confirmation email.

Until this point they won't appear in the mailchimp UI as a user but you also won't be to signup using the same email. You can either delete the pending subscription via curl `DELETE https://' .server. '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' .$listId. '/members/'. $memberId` or update the members details using a PUT cmd.

To confirm that the client has a pending subscription simply do a GET on your list. You should see all subscribers no matter their status.

For more info on status:
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/